# Android 2.2 (froyo) update available or not for myTouch Slide?

Tags: 2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

I haven't been able to keep up with the update calendars. But I did some google searches to find if the froyo update is available for T-Mobile's myTouch Slide. I heard the update was going to be live for most HTC devices around august but it's been awhile and I haven't gotten the update. Anyone know what I should do about this? 
Is it available? If so, can I install it manually?

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Answer (score 1):

[According to rumor, Mid October.](http://androidforums.com/t-mobile-mytouch-slide/181150-possible-date-froyo-got-customer-service-rep.html) However, I'm not the guy at that link. I won't swear to it but it's something to hope for

Comment: Oh thanks, because I haven't heard anything since the August dates.

Answer (score 0):

There's support for the myTouch Slide since CyanogenMod 6 which is Froyo-based, [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Slide).